# How to add multiple pictures to document without getting compressed (Office.Interop.Word)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ms-word, office-interop

How can I add multiple pictures to MS Word using Interop.Word assembly?
It is very important that it must be without losing quality. I've found I get the best quality result using the code that follows:

It inserts as an InlinePicture in order to get the scaling information, then removes the poor resolution graphic. The image is then inserted into a Shape object, the scaling corrected then the Shape is converted to an InlineShape as the final result.

How to ensure that each subsequent insertion does not replace the previous one.
Where do I need to insert `docRange.Collapse()` in this code or how to change the following code (where the variation using newShape gives the desired quality in the result):

```
            Application wordApp = new Application();
            Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add();
            float scaledWidth;
            float scaledHeight;
            Shape newShape;
            InlineShape finalInlineShape;
            Range docRange;
            foreach (var filepath in path)
            {
                InlineShape autoScaledInlineShape = wordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filepath);
                scaledWidth = autoScaledInlineShape.Width;
                scaledHeight = autoScaledInlineShape.Height;
                autoScaledInlineShape.Delete();

                newShape = wordDoc.Shapes.AddShape(1, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
                newShape.Fill.UserPicture(filepath);

                finalInlineShape = newShape.ConvertToInlineShape();
                finalInlineShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

                finalInlineShape.Range.Cut();
                docRange = wordDoc.Range();
                docRange.Paste();

            }   
            wordDoc.SaveAs2(@"C:\test\Project.docx");
            wordDoc.Close();
            wordApp.Quit();
```

Comment: You can take a look at [this MSDN sample project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-add-an-image-to-a-89ee4de7). They use the `Picture` class instead of `InlineShape`, which is the one you're using.

Comment: Your second code snippet manipulates the picture much less than the first: why don't you use the same technique? Also, please explain the loss in quality more exactly. One thing does stand out: You should use the RANGE object to accurately insert the graphic, not the Document object. And in order to ensure that each subsequent insertion doesn't replace the previous one, you need to COLLAPSE the Range after each insertion.

Comment: @CindyMeister could you possibly assist me in this updated question. How to Collapse the range. Kind,regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on further discussion in Comments I've edited the original question to make it clearer.

Considering the code you already have: the reason you're seeing only one image at the end is this:

```
 docRange = wordDoc.Range();
 docRange.Paste();
```

At the beginning of your code, declare an Object variable:

```
 object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
```

And change the lines to:

```
 docRange = wordDoc.Content; //better than using the Range() method
 //Optional, you may want this:
 //docRange.InsertParagraphAfter();
 docRange.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
 docRange.Paste();
```